# Python: escaping issue with ujson

Tags: python, json

I am using ujson to convert dictionary to json.
when I run the following line:

```
ujson.dumps({'key':'val\1'})
```

I get the following result:

```
[{"key": "val\\1"}]
```

while I expect/want it to be:

```
[{"key": "val\1"}]
```

any idea?

Comment: JSON uses double-quoted strings so the backslash has to be escaped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no problem, that's what `repr` looks like for this value. It *is* `\1`.